# How do I convert an existing column to Foreign Key?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a two tables.

Table `a` looks something like this -- first row is column names, both contain characters:

```
id |  tractce   | someString
1  |  "0011900" | "Label here"
```

Table `b`:

```
id | tractFIPS
1  | "0011900"
```

How do I convert `a.tractce` to a foreign key column referencing `b.id`?

So that it's:

```
id |  tractce | someString
1  |  1       | "Label here"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this in one step. You need to first add a new column that can hold the primary key of table `b`, then update table `a` and then add the foreign key and drop the old column:

```
alter table a add b_id int;

update a
   set b_id = b.id
from b 
where a.tractce = b.tractfips;


alter table a drop column tractce;
alter table a add constraint fk_a_b foreign key (b_id) references b;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/LPWNHK59722

Comment: Are you sure about this? This answer with some upvotes above seems to say its possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48510401/1993937

Answer (score 6):

This will add the constraint as long as there isn't any rogue data in the tables:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Name
FOREIGN KEY (ColumnName) 
REFERENCES TableName(ColumnName);
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to fix a typo and clarify it. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: you cant have a foreign key on columns that don't have the same data in (well you can but its never a good idea and would be pointless). You would have to match id to id or tractce to tractFIPS. the syntax would be the same

Comment: Am I right in assuming any existing data in the updated column would be lost ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it as you have asked:

```
UPDATE a SET tractce = b.id FROM b WHERE TRIM(a.tractce) = TRIM(b.tractfips);
ALTER TABLE a ALTER COLUMN tractce TYPE INTEGER USING (a.tractce::integer);
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT a_tractce_b_fk FOREIGN KEY (tractce) 
  REFERENCES b (id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

but better to rename `a.tractce` into `a.tractce_id`

```
ALTER TABLE a RENAME tractce TO tractce_id;
```